# WebApi2 basic header authorization : Not getting Custom error message with 401 status

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

Not getting custom error message which i am sending. IIS is overriding my custom error with

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

below is the response writing code -

actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                                "Invalid User");

Getting below message -
[image: getting below IIS message]

**Expected result "Invalid User"**

How to view my custom message. Someone help!

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I am using basic header authentication. Trying to send my custom message
in authorizeMortagegParticiPant.Message  with 401 status.

Comment: Can you provide more code than just that one line?

Answer (score 1):

The "Invalid User" text that you provided to the `CreateErrorResponse()` method is used for the error reason. Depending on the browser that you use, usually you don't see it on the page. You have to use the developer tools in your browser to see it.

If you want to display the message on the error page, you need to put it in the page content:

```
return new ContentResult {
  StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
  Content = "Invalid User"
};
```

However, some browsers will still not display the message, and will display their own messages associated with that code.